# Unicode Variation Selectors in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unicode, prawn

How do I encode a "Variation Selector" for a unicode code point in a Ruby string literal?

Background:

I render a PDF with the `prawn` gem where I use a font which has some glyphs which I need to encode with a variation selector. The code point is `\u0031`. I have read that I need to append the variation selector, but it doesn't seem to work, e.g. `"\u{0031FE02}"`, `"\u{0031}\u{FE02}"` or `"\u0031FE02"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer might be disappointing: ruby does everything well, but your target system might be unable to draw the resulting character properly. Look (Ubuntu 15.04):

```
▶ "\u{0061}\u{0300}"
#⇒ "à"   # perfect
▶ "\u{0061}\u{fe10}"
#⇒ "a︐" # uhmmm, at least she tried
▶ "\u{0061}\u{fe02}"
#⇒ "a︂"   # disgusting
```

Unfortunately, the support for different variation selectors in operating systems is still very limited. You might try to look whether your system is able to draw the combined correctly here: http://unicode-table.com/en/#variation-selectors